# Impala Query to Create Table of Dates for Outer Join

Tags: sql, lambda, impala

I want to create a temporary table that contains one field, Report_Date, and then populate it with trailing n days worth of dates.  I can do this outside of a query in R or Python, but looking for a way to do this in pure Impala SQL.

For example, I'd like to create the following table where *n* = 7:

| Report_Date |
| --- |
| 12/11/2020 |
| 12/10/2020 |
| 12/09/2020 |
| 12/08/2020 |
| 12/07/2020 |
| 12/06/2020 |
| 12/05/2020 |

I want to use this table to outer join to a table to find dates with missing data.

Is there some lambda function that I can define on use to do this?

Comment: You can do this. Basically this is called TOP-N query. It should be like this `select Report_Date from table ORDER BY Report_Date desc limit 7`. Order by will sort the data in order and the limit will limit the data till 7th row. Let me know if this is fine so i can mark this as answer.

Comment: Thanks Koushik, the problem is I don’t have a table. I want to query as a function of date(). For example, in oracle, you can select from DUAL.

Comment: sorry, i am confused. So do you want to create a series on the fly? If yes, you can use union to create `select now() union select now()-1...`. There is no dual in Imapala, you can issue a sql like `select now()` which is same as `select sysdate from dual`.